# Android studio still using Open jdk

Tags: java, android-studio

I installed `android studio 3` and `Java 9` but the `android studio` still using open `JDK` as per shown in task manager and using like 500mb of extra ram I have only 4gb of it, so what up with new open JDK thing in android studio and why it doesn't go away after installing Java JDK
I've set-up Java environment variable.

Comment: Yes! android studio best supports JAVA8, but still, you can use a higher version but believe me they will generate trouble for you.

Comment: so whats whrong here , java jdk or android studio